Power BI Measure Duplicating Rows
When creating a measure using the below expression and adding the measure to my table, it is duplicating rows, and I can't figure out why. Any thoughts?
Agenda Link = IF(LEN('public records'[Meeting Agenda])=0,"No","Yes")

Removing the measure also removes the duplicate row. Didn't change the expression much as I don't know what's causing it.

Try using a calculated column instead :
Agenda Link Column = IF(LEN('public records'[Meeting Agenda]) = 0, "No", "Yes")

Measures are evaluated in the context of your visual so when you add it, it might be evaluated multiple times and that's why you see duplicate rows.

That was the issue. A calculated column worked as intended. Thank you much!
